# iOS MVC implementation

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, custom-view

I have created an app, now, I need to re-write it in MVC.

I have created model classes say Event which are working fine. I have created a EventsListViewController which contains a tableview which will be notified when Events are loaded from Event model, I need to display the same events in two different table views and they perform different actions when a cell is tapped in each tableview.
EventsListViewController should not contain tableview.
I need to write two custom views which extends UITableView which uses the same models.

Can any one please suggest me to pass data between custom views <--> viewcontroller <--> model ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model -> Controller:

- Notifications
- KVO
- delegates

Controller -> Model

- direct reference to model

View -> Controller

- target-action
- delegates

Controller -> View

- outlets
- direct references

You should familiarise yourself with [this great course](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. When I have multiple custom views on one viewcontroller, target-action on the same viewcontroller involves more complexity, so can I keep target-action in custom views and pass data to controller through delegates?

Comment: Using MVC implementation, I should be able to use same controllers and models for both iPhone and iPad, if I use target-action in controllers which would lead to big change in controller if view gets changed, right?